# Twilio sms form works on local but not pushed to heroku - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, twilio

Newbie here to ruby on rails - haven't been able to figure out this issue. It's probably something very simple.

I've built a RoR site using Twilio's api / sms features so I can [send text messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms) to my users (using activeadmin and devise). Everything seems to work well on local but when I push up to Heroku I'm running into an issue.

Inside of activeadmin on my dashboard I added form fields to send sms
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXLrq.png)

I have inside of views > admin > dashboard > _send_a_message.html.erb and _send_message_all.html.erb I have

```
<%= form_tag('/send_sms', method: 'POST') do %>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter number" name="number">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter message here" name="message">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_tag('/send_sms', method: 'POST') do %>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter number" name="number">
<input type="text" placeholder="enter message here" name="message">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

I'm rendering those into the activeadmin dashboard and then in my 'TwilioController' I have these two:

```
def send_sms
 message = params[:message]
 number = params[:number]
 account_sid = 'my sid'
 auth_token = 'my token'

 @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

 @message = @client.account.messages.create ({:to => "+1"+"#{number}",
                                              :from => "+my number",
                                              :body => "#{message}"})
 redirect_to '/admin/dashboard', :flash => { :success => "Your message sent!" }

 rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
 puts e.message
end
```

and

```
def send_sms_all
 user_phones = User.where(:subscribed => true).pluck(:phone)
 message = params[:message]
 account_sid = 'my sid'
 auth_token = 'my token'

 @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

 user_phones.each do |number|
  @client.account.messages.create ({:to => "+1"+"#{number}",
                                    :from => "+my number",
                                    :body => "#{message}"})
 end 

 redirect_to '/admin/dashboard', :flash => { :success => "Your message sent!" }

 rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
 puts e.message
end
```

my routes are

```
post '/send_sms' => 'twilio#send_sms'
post '/send_sms_all' => 'twilio#send_sms_all'
```

This all seems to work locally fine - can send messages. When I push up to heroku and submit either form it directs me to /send_sms page which gives me the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." page and doesn't send the sms.

My heroku logs don't seem to have any 'error' indicated in them. Does this problem has something to do with get vs post maybe? I've already tried heroku run rake and db:migrate to make sure that was all set up and it seems fine.

Any help? Please let me know if you need to see something else.

**UPDATE:** I originally was calling on my secrets.yml file where my token and SID were stored and Heroku didn't like that. In my production.rb file I had this: config.middleware.use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token, '/send_sms', '/send_sms_all'

So I moved them into a .env file and called them like this instead:config.middleware.use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication, ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'], '/send_sms', '/send_sms_all' BUT that gave me a new issue of "Twilio Request Validation Failed." which I fixed by making the two '//send_sms', '//send_sms_all'.

Hopefully all this helps someone else in the future! Thank you to everyone who has helped out below!

Comment: How are you including your Account SID and Auth Token?

Comment: Inside where I wrote " account_sid = 'my sid'  auth_token = 'my token' ", I'm putting my actual SID and token... just took it out for the example as to not share them here. I also added them to my Heroku config variables.

Comment: Okay looks like the issue is an undefined method 'get_auth_token' in my production.rb - LOG: 2016-02-12T00:20:25.787535+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `get_auth_token' for #<Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication:...>) Not sure exactly what this means yet but I'm working on it.

Comment: How did you set up the the webhook authentication middleware in production.rb? Did you pass a block in?

Comment: My theory is that you aren't loading your account sid and auth token in to the application properly. Which, in the case of the middleware means that it is looking for a block to have been included, because `@auth_token` hasn't been set here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/lib/rack/twilio_webhook_authentication.rb#L22

Comment: You need to add your twilio keys to production. Run this in your console: `heroku config` do you see TWILIO keys there? If not, that is the issue.

Comment: when I run heroku config I do see my Twilio keys there.

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: I originally was calling on my secrets.yml file where my token
>   and SID were stored and Heroku didn't like that. In my production.rb
>   file I had this: `config.middleware.use
>   Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication,
>   Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token, '/send_sms',
>   '/send_sms_all'`
>
> So I moved them into a .env file and called them like this
>   instead:`config.middleware.use Rack::TwilioWebhookAuthentication,
>   ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'], '/send_sms', '/send_sms_all'` BUT that gave
>   me a new issue of "Twilio Request Validation Failed." which I fixed by
>   making the two `'//send_sms', '//send_sms_all'`.